# MVC app not connecting to Facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have an MVC app that I built as a POC.  When I run it in Visual Studio, it connects to FB and I get an access token and everything works beautifully.  However, when I publish the app to IIS, it no longer connects.  I get the FB login popup, enter my username and password and nothing happens.  It seems to not be hitting the auth.authResponseChange change event.  It's not hitting any of the alerts.  Here is the code I am using.  I'm at a loss as to what to try.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '<myappid>', // App ID
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });


    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
       alert("Connected!");
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            alert(accessToken);
            window.location = "/Home/FacebookLogin?token=" + response.authResponse.accessToken;
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            alert("User not Authorized!");
        } else {
            alert("User not Logged in!");
        }
    });
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
} (document));
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string token)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult FacebookLogin(string token)
    {
        HttpCookie accesstoken = new HttpCookie("accesstoken");
        accesstoken.Value = token;
        accesstoken.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10d);

        Response.Cookies.Add(accesstoken);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { token = token });
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Rhonda

Comment: Is the iis on the same computer? If not, you can debug the javascript using the Internet Explorer JavaScript built-in debugger pressing F12 and go to the script tab, maybe that helps.

Comment: It is on the same computer.  I was just publishing it so I could allow some other people on my team to have a look at it for test without having to publish it to another computer.

Comment: I would still try the built in JavaScript debugger for IE or Firebug for Firefox to see if silent exceptions occur.